# Accessing Thunderbird files from old computer

Tags: email

The computer I used for emails died recently, I have installed Thunderbird on a second machine and I have the hard drive from the dead machine attached as an external drive - can I recover the files on this disk into the current Thunderbird installation?

Comment: Yes, by simply removing any new profiles and putting yours in place, or changing the contents of the profile directory to match your old one.  Tricky part is where the files are stored, which is OS dependent.  What OS was the old computer, what is the OS on the new install?

Answer (score 0):

Open up the ProfileManager, create a new profile, do NOT configure it, close Thunderbird, copy the contents of your old profile into the newly created one. 
[official documentation](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Transferring_data_to_a_new_profile_-_Thunderbird)